# eclipse gives error on start up after adding sbteclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, sbteclipse

I add sbt eclipse plug-in .First I created the project named hello the in project directory i created a file named plugins.sbt and add this line in it

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")

and after the sbt> I typed eclipse then it created the project for eclipse 
when I open eclipse it gives me error message

An error has occurred. See the error log for more details 
The org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters plug-in extension "scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaElementFilter" specifies a viewer filter class which does not exist.
Plug-in org.scala-ide.sdt.core was unable to load class scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaElementFilter.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.scala-ide.sdt.core (806).

please help me to how to resolve this error and when I imported the sbt project eclipse give me another error

Building workspace has encountered a problem

Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder'.
Plug-in org.scala-ide.sdt.core was unable to load class scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.scala-ide.sdt.core (806).
Plug-in org.scala-ide.sdt.core was unable to load class scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.scala-ide.sdt.core (806).

Please help me 
scala version 2.11.1
sbt version 0.13
I added the scala-IDE plugin from this source 
http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html
i am using eclipse juno and pasted the following location in install new software

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/helium/e38/scala211/stable/site

my project compiles successfully in sbt

Comment: Your question is missing some details: Do you have installed [Scala-IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) in Eclipse? If so, which version? Which SBT version are you using? Does your project compile in SBT?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Eclipse Luna for Java Developers (as opposed to Eclipse Classic) AND Scala IDE 4.0 milestone 3? There is a known issue (solved in the nightly builds since then), reported on the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scala-ide-user/CAPaMnL5Fe6V8vUQo-09wOJj2zmVx00LVE6_Qd7CpXHr6L5wpMA%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer).

You can "fix" it by either upgrading the Scala plugin to a nightly build (they're pretty stable), or going with Eclipse Classic instead.